# localStorage only retrieves and saves 1 div

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to make a CMS of sorts that changes the text inside divs and save it, to do this I use localStorage. My problem is that it only changes one and doesn't work with the others. Here's the code for the HTML page where it can be changed:

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="project">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4> Project 1 </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive center block" />
            <div id="edit" contenteditable="true">
                original content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
function saveEdits() { 
    var editElem = document.getElementById("edit"); 
    var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML; 
    localStorage.userEdits = userVersion; 
    document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Opgeslagen!"; 
}

function checkEdits() { 
    if (localStorage.userEdits != null) 
        document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits; 
}
```

This is the page code where it should be shown. The `div` would be shown in the `<ol id="new-projects"></ol>`

```
<body>
    <b>Project vak 1</b>
    <ol id="new-projects"></ol>
```

```js
$("#new-projects").load("index.html #edit");
    $.getScript("js/vakjes/vak1.js",function(){
        document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits;
    });
```

It shows the edited text on the other page, but I can only do this one time
it won do it multiple times even when I change the variables.

Help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You know Local Storage is per-domain, right?

Comment: you know localstorage is local(only in your pc), right?